# ExpressJS : Difference between app.get() v/s api.get()/Router.get()

Tags: node.js, express

I have some understanding about this, but I still feel I am missing something. This is what my understanding so far:
`app.get()/app.post()` are used to make AJAX calls to the server primarily. Whereas, `Routes` are used to create APIs which are primarily used to talk to DB/backend.

Can somebody elaborate on this if there are more differences?

Comment: No, that's not it.  All of them are just different ways of attaching a callback function to a specific path request on your http server.  Each one is a route.  The router object is a means of collecting a bunch of different route handlers into one object, but a given route handler in a router has no different features than a given route handler set up via `app.get()`.  They are just different means of organizing route handlers.  Neither one has anything uniquely to do with an API.

Comment: It means I can use either app or Route to create APIs. If not, when to use app() and when to use Router. In my app, if have used app() to handle stuffs when URI on browser is changing and using Router() for rest.

Comment: As others have said, a router is just a means of grouping a bunch of route handlers (like a controller object in other systems).  You should use a router when your code organization benefits from grouping a bunch of route handlers together into a common object.  You can also use routers for sub-paths and make more modular code that way.  But, a router is really mostly a code organization tool that you can use when you find it helpful.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I understood from your comments and reading the docs in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for quick responses. I have found couple of docs on the net which describes them precisely and clears doubt about them. Please refer following two docs for reference:

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router

https://scotch.io/tutorials/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4

Answer (score 0):

Routers give your routes a level of nesting. You can think of them as "controllers" in more traditional MVC applications (where the actual router routes are methods on the controller).

You can define a Router object to be bound to `/foo/bar`, and every `.get()` `.post` or `.use()` you'll have there will be under the `/foo/bar` path, regardless.

It makes it useful to reuse components, because the insides route itself are not aware under what path it was called. So you can reuse the same route scheme in many applications, under different paths.

I tend to always use Router objects (even if it's only one and it's for `/`), because it makes the code read better and be more organized.

Answer (score 0):

Have you create any form with the method of get and post, if not create both feel the behavior.

Express Route method
**app.get()**
this through this function you can create GET api which may easily open via browser and get data from query string.

**app.post()**
this will create post url you can get data from body too.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. They are actually essentially the same thing. Routes are just more reusable/testable than just using the `app` instance.

For example:

```
app.get('/Posts/:id', ...
```

is equivalent to

```
var route = new Router();
route.get('/:id', ...

app.use('/Posts', route);
```

There is no limitations for what you can do in route vs app, so don't think about them separately from a functional level. It's more important for good architecture/testing/etc.